# Getting user and password from system/file in persistence.xml

Tags: java, mysql, xml, spring, hibernate

I am pretty new to spring/hibernate. I see that the DB connection settings in persistence.xml file is:

```
<properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tbm" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
```

I was wondering if it is possible to get the `user` and `password` values from System-properties.

**Context:** I have a Java Webapp which is packaged as `.war` file. In the war file, I don't see said xml anywhere, but I want  the **war** to work for system with different mysql credentials too, by just modifying some configuration file in the war.

Comment: Please check 9.4.1 in http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Comment: A datasource (which you configure in the server) is a much more flexible way of managing database connections than manual configuration. I recommend reading into that too.

Comment: @ArunM: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work for me. Its still showing unable to connect to user '', i.e. not fetching system properties.

Comment: @Gimby: Thanks, that's a nice workaround the problem, we've considered that, but we encountered some problem regarding password change because of different MySQL server versions. If this doesn't work out, we're going to restrict the MySQL version there.

Comment: @UjjwalKumar datasources are never a workaround. If anything, you're implementing a workaround right now. Just food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

In your Spring configuration xml file, add code:

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" cache-period="604800" />
```

In your webapp dir:
[image: config.properties]

in config.properties :

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tbm
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=
```

Use in spring configuration xml :

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
```